# Am new to Asp.Net and i just completed my first Application. How can i deploy to IIS server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need guidelines to follow on how to deploy my First ASP.net MVC Application to IIS and also a live server.

I have tried deploying to IIS, but when i browse it, localhost cannot connect.

Comment: Have you followed any tutorials? What problem did you experience, exactly? This process is pretty common

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the first thing you need to do is navigate to the following local URL (C:\inetpub\wwwroot) and there create the folder with your website name (project name)

Now Right Click on the project and there it says publish. Click on it.

A new window dialogue box will open which will say pick a publish target. There select the third option which says IIS, FTP, etc and click on publish

A Custom Profile Dialog Box will open for this configuration you can enter
 
**Publish Method**: Web Deploy

**Server**: localhost

**Site Name**: Default Web Site/Your Project name (WHich you named for the folder)

**Destination URL:** localhost/home/index

and that's it. The project will be published to the folder in the c drive and you can just upload those files to the server of your hosting.

Comment: By Right-click on the project I meant that by opening the project in visual studio and there right on the project not on the solution

Comment: Thnks Mazhar , i followed the steps to destination URL and then i click on next i see ApplicationDbContext and DefaultConnection which i copy n paste from my Web.config but i encounter an error while publishing "failed to create type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices